# three.js and depthFunc

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

From looking at the code, it seems that three does not give much control over the depthFunc. I would like to confirm that it's only set once as the default GL state, and not available say, in the material?

I'm not familiar with all examples, and was wondering if this is happening somewhere?

If not, what would be the best approach to set the depthFunc to gl.EQUAL for example, when a specific draw call is being made i.e. a mesh with a material?

Is something like toggling between scenes i.e. use one to render stuff, then use another one to render stuff on top of the first one a good solution for this? That's the only example that i've seen of tweaking the otherwise sorted objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently in the dev branch of three.js: [the pull request](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6344).